# Cambiar de estilo cuando cambio a la vista de semana en FullCalendar

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando fullcalendar en mi js, todo me funciona de forma correcta, pero solo tengo un conflicto, que cuando cambio a la vista de semana, me muestra con division de horas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero yo deseo que se muestra de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

segun estuve leyendo la documentacion, puedo agregarle el

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
             initialView: 'dayGridWeek'
});
```

pero no encuentro la manera, ya que al recargar la pagina quiero que me muestra la vista del mes, y cuando cambie a la vista de semana me muestre como yo deseo.

este es mi codigo actual del calendar:

```
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: "es",
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    events: fetchEvents,
    editable: false,
    dragScroll: true,
    dayMaxEvents: 10,
    eventResizableFromStart: true,
    customButtons: {
        sidebarToggle: {
            text: 'Sidebar'
        }
    },
    headerToolbar: {
        start: 'sidebarToggle, prev,next, title',
        end: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
    },
    direction: direction,
    initialDate: new Date(),
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    eventDidMount: function (info) {
        info.el.style.backgroundColor = info.event.backgroundColor;

        var fontSize = '1rem';
        info.el.style.fontSize = fontSize;
    },
    eventClassNames: function ({ event: calendarEvent }) {
        return []; // No necesitas agregar clases aquí, ya que estás manejando los estilos en eventRender
    },
    dateClick: function (info) {
        var date = moment(info.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        resetValues();
        sidebar.modal('show');
        addEventBtn.removeClass('d-none');
        updateEventBtn.addClass('d-none');
        btnDeleteEvent.addClass('d-none');
        startDate.val(date);
        endDate.val(date);
    },
    eventClick: function (info) {
        eventClick(info);
    },

    datesSet: function () {
        modifyToggler();
    },
    viewDidMount: function () {
        modifyToggler();
    }
});
calendar.render();
```

espero puedan ayudarme, gracias